# SCSS List Item Color Iteration

Tags: sass

I'm completely new to SCSS and I'm trying to set a background color to all items of a selector.

My css selector is the following, and returns all items (of two seperate UL lists)

```
#g-showcase .g-menu-item
```

I set a color array as:

```
$colors: #fad941, #ffffff, #e02520, #a6a6a6, #c6c6c6, #e02520;
```

I would like to iterate over my selector results and set a unique color from my color array (which could be larger than the above).

I started playing with some code, but I tackled it incorrectly, as I'm iterating over colors and not over selector items. (Don't know how to do that :( )

```
@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {

    #g-showcase li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
        background: nth($colors, $i)
    }
```

}

How could I achieve the desired result?

Thank you !

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is - as far as SASS is concerned - it's ignorant to how many li items your HTML code has, it's a pre-processor that never really see's the DOM, so it wouldn't know when to stop generating CSS

I assume what your looking to do is have the ability to select which color each li item has set as it's background, rather than as you currently have it, which is applying colors in the order they appear in the color array.

To do this you could add some additional markup to you HTML to give the generated CSS and slightly tweak how your creating the array, using a map instead. You might be looking to avoid polluting your HTML will erroneous mark-up, but the below would work.

```css
$colorz: (
foo:  #f24162, 
 bar: #591240, 
  fee: #4c5573, 
  fum: #6fa0a6, 
  eye: #71d9d9
);

@each $pointer, $bgcolor in $colorz
{
  #g-showcase li[pointer="#{$pointer}"] {
      background: $bgcolor;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="g-showcase">
    <li class="g-menu-item" pointer='bar'>The quick</li>
    <li class="g-menu-item" pointer='foo'>Brown Fox</li>
    <li class="g-menu-item" pointer='fee'>Jumped over</li>
  <li class="g-menu-item" pointer="bar">the lazy</li>
  <li class='g-menu-item' pointer="eye">dog</li>
</ul>
<ul id="g-showcase">
    
    <li class="g-menu-item" pointer="fum">...and other exciting stories</li>
  <li class="g-menu-item">that you hear from time-to-time</li>  
</ul>
```

***Note*** The above wont 'run' as it's sass, so there's a working version over on CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJLXMq